How can I have a @classmethod of a generic class act on the type parameter?
How can I call a classmethod by its generic only? Let's use following example:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

class Base(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def test(cls):
        print('foo')

class B(Base):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print('bar')

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def invoke_test():
        T.test()

a: A = A[B]
a.invoke_test()

I would imagine the result bar beeing printed, but instead 'TypeVar' object has no attribute 'test' will be risen. What am I missing? Python version 3.11.2 if that is of relevance.

Like the error says, T is a TypeVar in the scope you're referencing it from, not a reference to the actual class.
If you construct an instance of A with B as a parameter, then you can actually store that reference to B and use it in your invoke_test:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar

class Base(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def test(cls):
        print('foo')

class B(Base):
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        print('bar')

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

class A(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, gen_type: Type[T]):
        self._gen_type = gen_type

    def invoke_test(self):
        self._gen_type.test()

a = A(B)  # inferred type is A[B]
a.invoke_test()  # prints "bar"


No clue why my question got a downvote - would be great to know the reason. Anyway, thank you very much! That did the trick
